# Javascript link not clickable in IE 8 and below

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom

I'm creating a link on my button ([visible here](http://seocial.ly/fifth)) when the page is viewed in older versions of IE (8 and below).

```
if (ie < 9) { 
    document.getElementById('buttonOverride').innerHTML = 
    '<a href="/cam.html" target="_blank" alt="camera feed page">' + document.getElementById('buttonOverride').innerHTML + '</a>'; 
}
```

Where `ie` is a previously defined variable that identifies the IE version from the user agent.

This works, and the IE developer tools inspector tells me that the link has been inserted, but the link isn't clickable for some reason. Any ideas?

[image: IE8 developer tools say that the link is there, but it isn't clickable]

Comment: I wish. Unfortunately almost 20% of the audience is on older IE, so I do want the link working for them. 

I think I will place a little notification bar suggesting they get a better browser later on though.

Comment: With target="_blank", is it possible you have a problem with new windows opening, such as popupblocker, just an idea.

Comment: In the left bottom of your screen shot there is a warning sign. Probably it is some javascript error. Maybe if you start debugging the dev tools it will show something. Could'nt reproduce in my IE11.

Comment: Just removed it in case, still no luck (I'm running IE from a virtual machine with zero customization on it)

Comment: It's invalid to put a button inside an `<a>`, if that's what you're doing. *edit* yes that is what you're trying to do. Instead of doing that, just put (or alter) a "click" event handler on the button.

Comment: @Pointy: thanks, that looks like it's probably the answer, testing it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the onclick attribute of your override, or even the button itself.

```
if (ie < 9) { 
    var openCam = function () {
        window.location.href = '/cam.html';
    };

    document.getElementById('buttonOverride').setAttribute('onclick', 'openCam()');
}
```